# Antiforgery Token

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have finished a website with MVC.NET 4.0, and everything works perfectly on my localhost.  However, when I uploaded the site on my server, and try to login with my username and password, I am getting an error when I log in:-

```
   The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.
```

What is the problem exactly?  Do I need to alter anything in my login action of the account controller?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

given the brief info, I can only offer a guess at what might be wrong. The Web.config content settings influences behaviour.

If the anti forgorgery token is an SSL (Https) only cookie, and you connect to the website using HTTP only, the cookie is not sent. ( secure cookies not allowed on HTTP)

The receiving controller or controller actions marked to check the anti forgery token then fail.
AS teh browser doesnt have a cookie to send.

**Check browser accepts cookies and that HTTPs is being used.**

Comment: Hi soadyp, my website is Http, there is no https involved.  Do you need any more information?  Basically its my first mvc.net 4.0 website, and locally everything works fine. I do not have anything mentioned in my Web.Config, and am using the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] and     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
standard commands in mvc.net 4.0

Comment: I am going to pause this question if possible, because I think I have found out why.  Basically I am using a third party website to browse my website, since I cannot see it from where I am since the DNS has not been refreshed yet, and most probably that is why I am getting this error.

Comment: are you using   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()  hidden field ?   There may be another reason why the token isnt generated.  Can you see the hidden token on the page ?  keep looking...

Comment: btw ask the 3rd party about machinekey settings. Not the key itself.The key must be consistent across servers if this is to work.

Comment: Hi soadyp, I am going to wait till my DNS is propogated correctly, and then continue testing, since at the moment I have lots of errors which are due to this 3rd party.  Most prob everything is working fine, just need to test though.  Thanks for your help!